# Recursive function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I created recursive function like so.

```
function countDown(count){
    if(count==0){
        return;
    }
   countDown(count-1)
}

console.log(countDown(5))
```

The function returns undefined insted of printing numbers from 5 to 1.What i did wrong?

Comment: you never print some value.

Comment: Start debugging (even possible with pen and paper)

Answer (score 1):

You need ot print inside of the function.

```js
function countDown(count) {
    if (!count) return;
    console.log(count);
    countDown(count - 1);
}

countDown(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your code:

```
function countDown(count){
    if(count==0){
        return;
    }
   countDown(count-1)
}
```

If your variable named "count" is equal to zero it returns nothing.

Hence, undefined.

If your intention is to print numbers 5 - 1. Change your code like so:

```
function countDown(count){
    if(count==0){
        return;
    }

console.log(count);
   countDown(count-1)
}

countDown(5);
```

Comment: How to write this using Head recursion?

Comment: Please fix the indentation...

Comment: @Andreas sorry but i dont get it...

Comment: The comment is for @E.Maggini not you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a value from this function, basically.
It just goes every iteration and gets undefined as a return value

By default , any plain function (synchronous) will return undefined or will have a type of `void`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-void-and-when-to-use-void-type-in-javascript/

In this example , you'd better add a console.log of `count` variable before call a recursive function again. And just call it without `console.log(yourFunction)`

```js
function countDown(count){
  if (count === 0) return;
  console.log(count); // Just log it here
  countDown(count - 1);
}

countDown(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

you return nothing, so it's clear it will be undefined.

```js
function countDown(count){
    if(count==0){
        // you should return a value if you want value instead of undefined
        return 100;
    }
   countDown(count-1)
}

console.log(countDown(5))
```

Comment: What the func should do if count != 0?

Comment: You might want to test your answer...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you have to return a recursive function call

```
function countDown(count) {
  if(count==0){
    return;
  }
  console.log(count);
  return countDown(count - 1);
}
```

Comment: A recursive call doesn't have to return anything. Your version will still only return `undefined`. Also what's with that `console.log()`? Why is it there? What does it solve?

Comment: the task is implement function that takes number as argument and show range [arg, 1] in console. what's wrong?) it works correctly

Comment: You have that part right (show the counter). To be consistent, if you want to return something the 'return' if (count == 0) should return something, otherwise the first caller will get undefined... But OP does not make it mandatory. You could return the value of 'count' (is finally zero, and the first caller might need that info ).